# A count for loop

Tags: php

I have tried everything to get this to work and just cant get the count right.

```
<?php
$total = count($u);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $j = 0;
    $s = $database->checkUserPlayedRecent($u[$i]);
    if (mysql_num_rows($s) > 0){
        $j = $j + 1;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php echo "<td>$j</td>"; ?>
            <?php echo "<td>$u[$i]</td>"; ?>
            <?php echo "<td>$p[$i]</td>"; ?>
        </tr>
        <?
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to increment $j each time but ONLY for the results from num_rows.
Originally $j was $i + 1 but that wont work as I am not showing every result from the for loop, only those with num_rows returned. Any help here? Cheers

Comment: Move `$j = 0;` to before the outer loop?

Comment: Shorthand for `$j = $j + 1;` is `$j++;`.  I'm confused though.  Do you want `$j` to equal `mysql_num_rows($s)` or instead have `$j` just be your row number in the html table your drawing up?  If table row number, you want to put `$j = 0;` within your for loop declaration bit: `for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {}`.

Comment: Btw I think your code is a bit mixed up. Don't echo HTML with PHP and consider to use the alternative syntax for control structures: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $total = count($u);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) 
                    {
                        $j = 0;
```

$j assignment is inside the loop, so it's set to 0 every time. Just move it to right before the loop.

```
 $total = count($u);
                    $j = 0;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) 
                    {
```

Comment: This is crazy, I am sure I tried this!! 
But it works, thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your inner if to this:

```
                    if (mysql_num_rows($s) > 0)
                    {
                        $j = $j + 1;
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                                <?php
                                    echo "<td>$j</td>";
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                    echo "<td>$u[$i]</td>";
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                    echo "<td>$p[$i]</td>";
                                ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?
                    } else { // if no rows returned, hasn't played recently
                        echo "<tr><td>Hasn't Played</td></tr>";
                   }
```

At the moment, you're not accounting for no rows returned. Also, you may be able to avoid all the in-and-out of PHP by echoing or printing the whole thing in one shot. It's predictable enough that would be pretty simple.